# thread stops unwantingly

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that is running and performing a task repeatedly. I've implemented a counter to show me the iterations of the task performed by the thread. Every now and then I see that the counter is stuck somewhere and it's not increasing anymore. I don't receive any error or exceptions. The application runs but it looks like the thread just stopped without me asking it.

I will add some code to show the thread execution:

notice the int "c" - thats the counter for iterations.

```
public void check() {
    Thread check = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            for (;;) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Update GUI here on EventQueue.

                        try {
                            Task.readTasks();
                        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (NoteInfo == null || NoteInfo == "") {
                            btnViewNote.setEnabled(false);
                        } else {

                            btnViewNote.setEnabled(true);
                        }

                        textField.setText(Task.printNextTask);
                        c++;
                        lblCycle.setText("Cycle: " + c);

                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    // Task.initializeIt();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    break;
                }
                if (killcheck)
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
    check.start();
}

public static void stopChecking() {
    killcheck = true;
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    textArea.setText("");
    textField.setText("");
    c = 0;
    lblCycle.setText("Cycle: " + c);

}
```

Comment: I would put a print statement before the break to see did the thread ended. I will also put a print statement just before the c++ statement. I will also fire up my debugger and suspend the thread when the counter stops increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check thread gets interrupted by another thread. Print the stack trace in the catch block and verify it.

```
  try {     
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       // Task.initializeIt();
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {    
          //   break;          // just ignore it
  }
```

Comment: Never ignore InterruptedException. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: That doesn't seems to be the issue, I did what you say and the stack trace isn't printed.

Comment: @artbristol: Atleast in this particular case, `killCheck` variable serve that purpose. +1.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley in that case, the catch block should set `killcheck` to true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the definitions of `killcheck` or `c` but it is possible that these have not been marked as `volatile`?

If multiple threads are reading and writing a shared value then there must be some sort of synchronization otherwise they could be dealing with stale values.  You can either use one of the atomic classes such as `AtomicBoolean` or `AtomicInteger`, use the `synchronized` keyword, or mark the variable as `volatile`.  All three would allow the main thread and the inner thread to see each other's changes to the shared fields.

```
volatile int c;
volatile boolean killcheck;
```

For posterity, here's how you use the atomic classes:

```
 final AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
 final AtomicBoolean killcheck = new AtomicBoolean();
 ...
         c.incrementAndGet();
 ...
         if (killcheck)
             break;
 ...
         killcheck.set(true);
 ...
         c.set(0);
```